# Which data type is more apt to store generic data without any data loss

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, ssis

We've a excel macro that queries data from third party and loads the data into excel sheet. And SSIS job will do necessary transformations i.e, data type transformations and loads data into data tables.

Now we are planning to replace macro with .net component that will load data from third party into staging tables and a SSIS job will load data into actual tables.

So, is it advisable to have data types of columns in staging tables as nvarchar without any data loss. Please let me know if I need to provide any additional info.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with .Net and Excel, it appears that it is good to have  [SQL Variant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173829.aspx) in the database. If necessary, either in SQL or in an application casting can be made (if you know the type of data) . In SQL you can use for this purpose [SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY (expression, property)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178550.aspx) with gives you the type of stored data.